# Styling of Even/Odd Divs in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to style the odd and even classes but the code is not working as intended. Its styling all the classes as one. This will be more understandable through my code and output.
**OUTPUT:**
[image: There are multiple divs like these and its styling them the same which i dont want obviously]
**CODE:**

```css
.b1-segment:nth-child(even) .description-wrapper{
  color: white;
  float: left;
}
.b1-segment:nth-child(odd) .description-wrapper{
  color: black;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
  {getallservices.map((service) => {

              return(
                <>
                <Fade bottom>
                   <section className="services banner-page about  b1-segment bg-fx" style={{ backgroundImage:   `url(${service.imgDesk.fluid.src})` }}>
                      <Container>
                        <Row>
                          <Col md={12}>
                              <div className="description-wrapper">
                                  <h3>{service.servicesHeading}</h3>
                                  <p>{service.description.description}</p>
                                  
                              </div>
                          </Col>
                        
                        </Row>
                      </Container>
                   </section>
                </Fade>
             
                </>

              )

            })}
```

Answer (score 2):

Within `<Fade bottom>` `.b1-segment` is the only child. So `.b1-segment:nth-child(odd)` will always be selected.

If you want to select `.b1-segment` as direct child you have to make the `section` tag as main wrapper. Then `.b1-segment` will be considered as child within where it's rendering and your css will work.

```
  {getallservices.map((service) => {

          return(
            <>
              <section className="services banner-page about  b1-segment bg-fx" style={{ backgroundImage:   `url(${service.imgDesk.fluid.src})` }}>
                <Fade bottom>
                  <Container>
                    <Row>
                      <Col md={12}>
                          <div className="description-wrapper">
                              <h3>{service.servicesHeading}</h3>
                              <p>{service.description.description}</p>  
                          </div>
                      </Col>
                    </Row>
                  </Container>
                </Fade>
              </section>
            </>
          )
        })}
```

Comment: i tried it, output is the same as before its still not considering both nth childs... i know theres a small mistake somewhere but i cant seem to find it.